# How to count distinct companies in Leads

Tags: reporting, leads

As Company is a text field in Leads, I cannot figure out how to count the number of distinct companies we have for all our Leads. Is there a work-around? Thanks.

Comment: What have you researched/tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [COUNT_DISTINCT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) aggregate SOQL query.

```
SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(Company)
FROM Lead
```

Comment: OK will do. Thank You!